# Factorising cubic polynomial given 1 factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

> Given that $x^3-x^2-17x-15 = (x+3)(x^2+bx+c)$ where $b$ and $c$ are constants, find the values of $b$ and $c$.

I don't know how to easily solve this question. I could use polynomial long division but these seems overly complicated especially since at this point in the textbook I am using, that hasn't even been covered yet.

Comment: It can easily be solved by polynomial division:  $\dfrac{x^3-x^2-17x- 15}{x+3}$

Comment: Do you know how to expand a formula ?

Comment: @amWhy I know but there has to be a simpler way especially since polynomial long division has not been covered in my textbook yet

Answer (score 5):

Multiply out and you'll get that

$$x^3 - x^2 - 17x - 15 = x^3 + (3+b)x^2 + (3b + c) + 3c $$

Thus we must have that $3c=-15, 3b+c=-17, 3+b = -1$. It's not hard to get that $c=-5$ and $b=-4$

Comment: Thank you @Stefan4024. That's very simple and I do not know how I didn't see that

Comment: @SaulMcShane You're welcome.

Comment: I really wonder why the answer deserved so much downvotes

Comment: I really don't understand either. (I upvoted it). Thank you, I appreciate it

Comment: @SaulMcShane I wasn't refering to you, but to the downvoters in general. I'm sorry if there was any misunderstanding.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I had one more downvote than you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yeah, it's weird, as the answers were posted at more or less the same time and are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^3 - x^2 - 17 x - 15 &= x^3 + 3 x^2 - 4 x^2 - 12 x - 5 x - 15\\
              &= x^2 (x + 3) - 4 x(x  +  3) - 5(x + 3)\\
               &= ( x + 3)(x^2 - 4 x - 5)
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Let $x_2,x_3$ be the other two roots, then by Vieta's formulas $-3+x_2+x_3=1$ and $-3x_2x_3=15$. Therefore $x_2+x_3=4$ and $x_2x_3=-5$, so $x_2,x_3$ are the roots of the  quadratic $x^2-4x-5$ which must then match the other factor $x^2+bx+c$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a reason why.